# How to paginate all Youtube Data API search results

Tags: youtube, pagination, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the Youtube Data API to search for upcoming event by search query.

The specific query is 
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&eventType=upcoming&q=vs&type=video&key={api_key}`

The pageInfo.totalResults returned is ~150272

Though when I try to paginate them, I only get through 147 items until the items array is empty in the response, and the nextPageToken is the same on every response, such that I continue to loop trying to get more results (eating up my API quota) and none are returned. Is this a bug?

Comment: The nextPageToken should be different, not sure where is the issue. But I thought you can improve the query a bit by using `maxResults`. By default is 5. Maximum you can requests is 50.

Comment: I agree. That doesn't change the behaviour but interestingly after running more tests, the page tokens have particular values when they get stuck, even for different search parameters. specifically `prevPageToken: CP8BEAE` and `nextPageToken: CLECEAA` or `prevPageToken: CJUDEAE` and `nextPageToken: CMcDEAA`

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this [document - Paging through results](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Paging_through_Results), API responses use [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_link) tag to identify `pagination` links for the previous and/or next page of entries in a feed. To avoid pagination problems, Official documentation recomment that you see these links to enable users to link to different pages of API results.

The API uses the [start-index](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#start-indexsp) and [max-results](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#max-resultssp) request parameters to determine which results to include in an API reponse. In addition, API responses use the  tag to approximate the total number of entries in a feed.

```
<openSearch:startIndex>26</openSearch:startIndex>
<openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
<openSearch:totalResults>107</openSearch:totalResults>
```

Comment: I think you might be referring to the Data API v2.0. That link now redirects to the v3 docs and they don't refer to any `start-index` or `max-results` properties

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps give this function a try to solve Pagination for you:

```
    public static async Task<List<T>> ExecuteRequest<T>(dynamic request, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        string nextPageToken = "";
        var result = new List<T>();
        do
        {
            request.MaxResults = 100;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nextPageToken))
                request.PageToken = nextPageToken;
            var response = await request.ExecuteAsync(cancelToken);
            nextPageToken = response.NextPageToken;

            result.AddRange(response.Items);

        } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nextPageToken));

        return result;
    }
```

And put it to use something like this:

```
    private async Task GetPlaylistAsync(string playlistId)
    {

        var request = Client.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
        request.PlaylistId = playlistId;

        var videos = await Functions.ExecuteRequest<Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.PlaylistItem>(request, CancellationToken);
    }
```

You can easily modify this to however your version of the YouTubeApi works with pagination.